# Open swiftUI view in UIAction

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I have TableViewController file. There is also another swiftUI view file knows as pictureView made in swiftUI

```
let actionNext = UIAction(title: "Next", image: UIImage(systemName: "arrow.forward.circle.fill")) { action in
            print("action next clicked")
        }
```

I want to open pictureView() by these action

Comment: You definitely need to read more about SwiftUI in general, but [here](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/swiftui-programmatic-navigation/) is a possible solution for question.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use a SwiftUI view in UIKit directly. So you need to embed it into a `UIHostingController` instead:

```
let pictureHostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: PictureView())
pictureHostingController.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
navigationController?.pushViewController(pictureHostingController, aniated: true)
```

If i understood your question correctly, this should be the solution

Comment: Thanks for reply on this. can you explain third line ?

Comment: Like what is pushViewController  and aniated here

Comment: It's a typo: "animated" not "aniated"